# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.> Unable to compute hash of ..\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\..\release\classes.jar

Tags: integration, proguard

I am getting the following error message when I enable Proguard from gradle file and to generate an release build file.

> Exception while processing task  java.io.IOException:
>   proguard.ParseException: Expecting type and name instead of just '***'
>   before '(' in line 169 of file
>   'S:\workspace\Projects..\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules..\release\aapt_rules.txt'
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:117)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Error:proguard.ParseException:
>   Expecting type and name instead of just '***' before '(' in line 169
>   of file
>   'S:\workspace\Projects..\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules..\release\aapt_rules.txt'
>     at
>   proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:908)
>     at
>   proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:748)
>     at
>   proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:534)
>     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:165)
>     at
>   proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.getConfiguration(ProGuardTask.java:1142)
>     at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)    at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
>     ... 4 more
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageProRelease'. > Unable to compute hash of
>   S:\workspace\Projects\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\Pro\release\classes.jar

I am using following libraries in the code:

1. AndroidScanLib.jar
2. apache-mime4j-core-0.7.jar
3. httpclient-4.1.2.jar
4. httpmime-4.2.3.jar
5. libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar
6. MobileImagingEngine.jar
7. MobileImagingEngine_Doc.jar
8. SmartScan.jar
9. sqlcipher.jar

Comment: Having the same issue.. Have you got the problem solved? Pls let me know by commenting here @Anshul

Comment: same problem here...

Answer (score 6):

A weird workaround: disable minifyEnabled (minifyEnabled false), generate signed APK, and then re-enable it (minifyEnabled true) and generate the signed APK again. Hope this works.

Comment: this didn't work for me either. I am able to build the signed apk build when minify is set to false.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i was using a custom library that i created and i had set minifyEnabled true, and in the dependent module i again did same minifyEnabled true. keeping this at only one place solved my problem. Same can be case with libraries other than your own!